# What is the difference between ->middleware(['api']) and ->middleware(['auth:api'])?

Tags: laravel

If I look at the Laravel authentication page, I will find an article that says middleware(['api']) and an article that says middleware(['auth:api']).

Which one is using auth.php?

Comment: for api prefix endpoints you can use auth.api middleware , while auth for all included route,api etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The middleware named `api` is a middleware group, not a single middleware. It is defined in `app/Http/Kernel.php` in the `protected $middlewareGroups`.

The middleware named `auth` is a single middleware that takes a parameter or several. `auth:api` means you are instructing the `auth` middleware to use the `api` Authentication guard. This guard is defined in `config/auth.php`. The `auth` middleware is defined in `app/Http/Kernel.php` in the `$routeMiddleware` array which shows what class it is referring to. It is the authentication middleware for your application.