# Assigning the same middleware in controllers and routes

Tags: php, laravel

I'm new to Laravel and PHP, and I'm recently reading a [tutorial](https://www.positronx.io/laravel-jwt-authentication-tutorial-user-login-signup-api/). First they declared the `auth:api` middleware in app/Http/Controllers/AuthController.php

```
public function __construct() {
    $this->middleware('auth:api', ['except' => ['login', 'register']]);
}
```

And later they did it again in routes/api.php

```
Route::group([
'middleware' => 'api',
'prefix' => 'auth'], function ($router) {
Route::post('/login', [AuthController::class, 'login']);
Route::post('/register', [AuthController::class, 'register']);
...
});
```

I deleted the `Route::group` statement and took the routes out

```
Route::post('/login', [AuthController::class, 'login']);
Route::post('/register', [AuthController::class, 'register']);
...
```

and it still works the same.

So my questions are:

1. Where does the `api` in `'middleware' => 'api'` come from? Is it the same thing as `auth:api`? But I checked `$routeMiddleware` in Kernel.php, and it doesn't have the key `api`.
2. `login` and `register` shouldn't use any middleware, yet they're included in the route group, and I can register and log in fine. Why? Shouldn't it reject me because I don't have a token?
3. If I only want to declare the middleware in api.php, what should the middleware's name be? Is just `api` ok?

Comment: Part of your answer is here, https://stackoverflow.com/q/63955613/296555

Comment: The other part is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68033679/what-is-the-role-of-api-middleware-in-laravel/68033808#68033808

Answer (score 0):

I agree that can be confusing.

1. `'middleware' => 'api'` refers to a `$middlewareGroups` array entry located just a bit further down in `Kernel.php`.

```php
'api' => [
  'throttle:240,1',
  'bindings',
],
```

It's not the same as `auth:api` which is an authentication guard, see [here](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/authentication#specifying-a-guard).

2. However you still should probably have those middlewares on your `login` and `register` routes to throttle and perform route model binding.
3. You would use whatever middleware is appropriate for your authentication mechanism.  For Passport, this is `auth:api`, I think it's `auth:sanctum` for Sanctum, and I think `web` if you're using the built-in.  You can name these whatever you want; they get defined in `config/auth.php`.